# Replace Line Break VTL

Tags: line-breaks, vtl

I need to replace all line breaks with a ^ character using VTL. I unfortunately do not know which version of VTL I am using as it is used as the formula language within an application. Please see below with what we have so far:

```
#if($FIELD} !="")
#set($new = "
 ")
${$FIELD}.replaceAll("$new", "^" )
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in the Hex code for Line Feed(0A)"

`#if($FIELD.contains(//0A)) #set($FIELD2=$FIELD.replaceAll("//0A", "^")) $FIELD2`